# Convert Python Script to exe and include selenium browser

Tags: python, selenium, exe

I got problems while converting.
I tryed:
Auto py to exe - gui - I added chromedriver(1 file)  || whole folder(site-packages\chromedriver_binary)
I created .spec file and wrote there:

```
a = Analysis(['tk.py'],
binaries=[],
datas=[("chromedriver.exe",".")])
```

But got some errors:

> File "c:\python36_32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\buildne
>   782, in build with open(spec, 'r') as f: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2]
>   No such file or directory: 'tkk.spec'

I have got .spec, chromedriver and python script in same folder.

When i'm run exe on Windows 7 i got something like it:
https://gyazo.com/0152ca0998e2e0895ff91c9cfb7db0c2
I have got no clue how to stop view of console to read error

Can you tell what's I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

One way to preserve this error is to run tk.exe through the command prompt / terminal. On Windows this can be done by opening cmd, changing your directory to the location of tk.exe and executing `./tk.exe` which will run the executable and preserve the output for you to see.

From what I can see (it's not clear), you are getting a `FileNotFoundError` saying "Nie mozna odnalezc okreslonego pliku" which I believe is `The specified file can not be found` in English. Below this, selenium has raised an error saying that `chromedriver.exe` cannot be found.

Looking at the video you provided, it looks like you used onefile mode. If you did some research on [bundling files with PyInstaller's --onefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile/13790741#13790741) then you would know that you will need to tell selenium specifically where chromedriver.exe is.

*I have not done this myself* but I believe the process would look something like:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.binary_location = resource_path('.')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

Of course this won't be everything but this is telling selenium to look at the scripts temporary directory (due to --onefile) for chromedriver.exe

Also as a quick note, you said you used auto-py-to-exe. When using this tool, it tells you explicitly to take this into consideration when adding files and using --onefile.